# How to fix Listen EADDRINUSE in ubuntu

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, port

How can I resolve this issue?

```
1|server   |     at listenInCluster (net.js:1327:12)
1|server   |     at Server.listen (net.js:1414:7)
1|server   |     at Object.<anonymous> (/root/signalmaster/server.js:41:8)
1|server   |     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
1|server   |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
1|server   |     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
1|server   |     at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
1|server   |     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
1|server   |     at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/ProcessContainerFork.js:27:21)
1|server   |   code: 'EADDRINUSE',
1|server   |   errno: 'EADDRINUSE',
1|server   |   syscall: 'listen',
1|server   |   address: '::',
1|server   |   port: 8080 }
```

My `server` and `turnserver` status is `Online` but our clients can't communicate or see each other.

UPDATE:

[see this pm2 list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pUgLc.png)

Comment: This error means your port (8080) is already in use by another service. Either use a different port, or stop the service which uses 8080

Comment: Hi @NullDev, I just want to stop ut, how can I do it?

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply. I just need to stop it, how can I trace services that uses port 8080?

Comment: if you're on Linux, you could try `sudo kill -9 $(lsof -t -i:8080)`

Comment: I already execute that code, but when I get into `pm2 logs` the error still exist.

Comment: If I run `sudo netstat -lpn | grep :8080` I get this result `tcp6   0   0 :::8080   :::*   LISTEN   5065/server   .js`

Comment: Well, you didn't mention your server was started by PM2. In this case do `pm2 list`, note down the ID of the script you want to stop and finally run `pm2 delete YOUR-ID-HERE`. Optionally, if you want to stop all scripts, just write `pm2 delete all`

Comment: When I dot `pm2 list` it show the `turnserver & server` but I need this two. And their status is both `online`

Comment: Might be the `server.js` is using the port:8080?

Comment: You can't use the same port for both services. You need to change one of them.

Comment: Okay but before it's working perfectly this was after I restarted the Alibaba Instance, then do `pm2 resurrect`.

Comment: Anyways, how can I change the port anyone of them?

Answer (score 0):

try in the console :
`killall node`
and the problem should be fixed

Answer (score -1):

```html
The following IP address already used. In same IP address you can run the server by different ports. The port must be opened.

* If it's live server and already running httpd .


<VirtualHost  *:80>
ServerName api.xxxx.com
#DocumentRoot /var/www/test
CustomLog       /var/www/test/access.log common
ErrorLog        /var/www/test/error.log
UseCanonicalName Off
    UserDir disabled

<Location "/">
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyPass http://localhost:8080/
        ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:8080/
    </Location> 

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: This question is about a NodeJS Server running on Port 8080. There is no mention of an Apache webserver.

Comment: Yes, I just want to kill the port `8080`, but I already did the `sudo kill` & `sudo kill $()` still nothing happens when I check the `pm2 logs` still got same error.